# Can a process with a unit root still be stationary?

Tags: time-series, stochastic-processes, stationarity, unit-root

It is quite clear, by expanding the inverse lag polynomial, that a process without unit roots will be weak-stationary.

However, I'm not finding anywhere a proof of the other implication: to be weak stationary requires no unit root.

My thinking is that even if the inverse lag polynomial does not have a convergent power series expansion around 0, the process may still be stationary for some other reason, right?

Comment: one non formal proof is that, if you have a unit root, then the variance is increasing which makes the series non- weakly stationary because  a weakly stationary series needs to have constant variance. but note that unit roots are not the way to have  weakly non-stationarity.

Comment: *It is quite clear, by expanding the inverse lag polynomial, that a process without unit roots will be weak-stationary.* It is the obvious things that people tend to get wrong in proofs. Absence of a unit root is not a sufficient condition for stationarity.

Comment: @RichardHardy It is for weak-stationarity, right? If not, can you clarify?

Comment: This holds for both weak and strict stationarity. A process without a unit root but with a linear trend in mean (or even in variance) is nonstationarity whichever way you look at it.

Comment: @RichardHardy Ah yes sure, I implicitly meant the process after subtracting deterministic parts.

Comment: Yeah, I think having a unit root in, say, the logarithm of the conditional variance would be a problem, too.